# PC game where you are a writer/journalist sent to small english village by mysterious caller. game about ghosts and occult

Tags: story-identification, horror, video-games, ghost

I played a mystery game around 10 years or so ago. I believe you are a writer or journalist who receives a mysterious call to check out a small English village on the ocean. I am quite certain you have an English accent and are a man. I remember having to walk through the woods and it was quite foggy. The village seems to be misplaced from time. The colors of the game are dull/muted.

I remember at some point receiving a call from the same mysterious caller in a red English booth within the village. There were also ghosts. Not a shooter game but and similar to a point and click but I think you actually had to use controls to walk around. I also remember a part where you enter a cave from the beach and find something related to a mysterious ritual.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: One of these, perhaps? The style you're describing is generally referred to as a "walking simulator"; https://store.steampowered.com/tags/en/Walking+Simulator

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlast?

Comment: https://store.steampowered.com/app/624270/The_Painscreek_Killings/?

Comment: [Everybody's Gone to the Rapture](https://killscreen.com/previously/articles/everybodys-gone-rapture-triumph/)?

Comment: @Valorum zero chance this is _Outlast_. No village, no ocean, no ghosts (well, there's a ghostly-ish entity, but it's not a ghost), no cave, tremendous amounts of running, escaping and hiding and a general ambiance which I think wouldn't just be remembered as a regular point and click

Answer (score 3):

Could this be *The Vanishing of Ethan Carter*?

> In The Vanishing of Ethan Carter, you play as Paul Prospero, an occult detective who receives a disturbing letter from Ethan Carter and realizes that the boy is in grave danger. When Paul arrives in Ethan’s home of Red Creek Valley, he realizes things are even worse than he imagined. Ethan has vanished in the wake of a brutal murder, which Paul comes to see might not be the only murder to investigate. Using both regular and supernatural detective skills, Paul must figure out what happened to the missing boy.
>
> <sub>— [IGDB, *The Vanishing of Ethan Carter*](https://www.igdb.com/games/the-vanishing-of-ethan-carter)</sub>

Answer (score -3):

Maybe one of the Mystery Case Files games. Escape from Ravenheart, maybe.

Comment: Could you explain how that matches the description given in the question?